# ansible: sudo -iu for interactive shell

Tags: ubuntu, automation, ansible

Is there a better way of writing `sudo -iu username -command-` for every command in ansible when interactive shell is needed?

Example:

```
- name: Install nodejs {{ node_version }}
  shell: sudo -iu {{ nvm_user }} nvm install {{ node_version }} && sudo -iu {{ nvm_user }} nvm alias default {{ node_version }}
  when: not np.stat.isdir is defined
```

Comment: The need here is to read .bash_profile to get environment set-up ?

Comment: Yes, as I would normally ssh to a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask Ansible to sudo for you, and invoke `bash` directly like so :

```
- name: Install nodejs {{ node_version }}
   sudo_user: "{{ nvm_user }}"
   sudo: true
   shell: bash -lc 'nvm install {{ node_version }} && nvm alias default {{ node_version }}'
   when: np.stat.isdir is not defined
```

A few notes :

- `Install nodejs {{ node_version }}` won't get interpolated
- You can replace `not x is defined` with the more natural `x is not defined`
- You might want to add '`changed_when:` to control the changed state of your command, so your taks is idempotent (but it seems that you only run the task when some directory doesn't exist already, so I guess the task state can only be `skipped`/`changed`)

Comment: Ow `bash -lc` yes, totally forgot that one :).

Comment: `bash -lc` did not work for me, but `bash -lci` did.